# Detect connection

Tags: c, sockets

I have a server (in c on windows) just listen on many sockets. 
I have to detect if some of those sockets doesn't send data from more than xx minutes. 
And in that case I have to close that specific connection.

I have studied keep alive parameter but I have not still idea how to implement this requirement.

Thanks
Rosario

Comment: Keepalive has exactly nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `struct` containing a socket handle and a timestamp of the last time data was received on that socket.  When a client connects, put it in a list/array and set the timestamp.  When a client disconnects (or you close it), locate that socket in the list/array and remove it.  Each time new data is received, locate that socket in the list/array and update its timestamp.  You can then loop through that list/array periodically looking for expired timestamps.